# Is it really possible to get to the End City without killing the Ender Dragon like in this video?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I watched a video about how to get to the End Cities without killing the Dragon:

It shows how to find the End Cities without killing the Dragon. The player builds a redstone/slimeblock flying machine in the end to fly across the void.

Can this really be done? I'm not so sure if this is possible for not.

Comment: Side note: Considering the like:dislike ratio, i  would imagine if it didn't work there would be a lot more dislikes and comments complaining about, i would assume it does work, although it does seem risky and a little unreliable in building the flying machine.

Comment: Its a new video so there are very less likes and dislikes, so i can't compare.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about verifying the authenticity of a random video.  We are gamers, not verifiers of videos, even if they are about games.

Comment: @Frank Remove the video then. The question becomes "is it possible to do a thing", which is most definitely on-topic.

Comment: @Studoku That is.  Which the question has been edited to asking.  That's a much better and on-topic question than asking us to verify crazy rumor video # 432532.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appearently, it's possible to do this. But I wouldn't recommend because of the following reasons:

1. It's too far. According to the video, the other End islands are about 1,000 blocks away.
2. Use it at your own risk! This could be dangerous and you may fall into the Void because of this.

There are a few ways to get across.

1. Not recommended, but you may try. Build far away from the center island into the other islands.
2. Make a machine. This requires a few redstone blocks, sticky and non sticky pistons, glass, and slime blocks. Use it to get across.

I have tried going to the island with killing the Dragon by flying in Creative and of course I found them. So it's possible, but has a lot of disadvantages to it. I would recommend killing the Ender Dragon and then go to the portal to the End Cities.

Basically, the End Gateway you get when killing the Dragon teleports you to the outer islands and is faster.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. I built it and it worked fine. However, I would not recommend building it, there are lots of risks involved and it takes forever.