# Finding the End city

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have killed the Ender dragon in my survival world in **1.8**, so the End island was also generated in 1.8.

I have been searching for the teleporter that teleports you to one of the islands around the main island. It spawns after defeating the Ender dragon, but I did not find it. This is probably caused because killing the Ender dragon in Minecraft 1.8 **did not** trigger the teleporter.

**Is it possible to find an End city after updating Minecraft from 1.8 to 1.9?**

Comment: You can try this video, i think it may work :- http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/262070/139312

Comment: Related: [Finding multiple End cities](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266402/finding-multiple-end-cities)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the best solution is just to remove old map of the END and let it generate again - by new methods of generation and also with new dragon and cities.

The thing is that even main island is generated in new behaviour, which may be the problem why even after another kill of dragon you won't find any portal or so. (It may be just bugged inside of blocks or so, or it may not even be there)

You can do it by deleting region files from your save, but be sure you are NOT in that dimension and that you will lose all buildings in the end. For being sure, make a backup.

Wiki:

> The End is saved in the same way normal worlds are, in the DIM1 subdirectory of the world save.
>
> Deleting the DIM1 directory will reset the End, and all man-made buildings will be deleted.

Pros:

- You will get the new main island with new towers
- new dragon
- no glitches due to different "old generation" and "new generation" of terrain
- after defeating the dragon you will get outer islands for sure, too.
- New blocks will be generated even on main island

Cons:

- You will lose any buildings in the End

Answer (score 4):

Yes but you have to spawn a new ender dragon after you've updated to 1.9.

Players can re-spawn the ender dragon  by placing four ender crystals atop the exit portal, one on each side.

ender crystal craft guide -> https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Crystal

after respawning the dragon and killing it, a portal will spawn

Comment: I doubt that spawning of dragon that way would work, because new 1.9 maps have pre-generated portal , however old maps do generate portal when dragon dies. Also the towers won't be on same spots - and when you summon the dragon, it repairs those towers, too. So this probably won't work or will be bugged. But it needs testing.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík It does work.  Etho did it in his LP; the old portal is deactivated and a new one is created at the center where it would normally generate, and more towers are made.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Well, then still there is place for glitches, badly positioned towers and so, which can make it unpretty. And if the original island had other proportions than the one that would be generated in new version, also portals might be misplaced. However that is all dependant on individual seeds I think.