# End data folder location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have asked a question how to find the End city if I have updated my game from 1.8 to 1.9 and already killed the Ender dragon and generated the End island in 1.8 (see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264310/finding-the-end-city)). I got an answer from Antoine Hejlík (see in link) and he recommended to delete the files that contain the End data, so I can generate the End again in 1.9. I have already made a backup, but **I dont know where can these files be found** I just know it is in **.minecraft/saves/myworld/**???.

I would be glad if someone knew what should replace the ??? above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the myworld/DIM1 folder (it is in fact mentioned in the linked answer). Also it would be good to make a backup before deleting it.