# Finding multiple End cities

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to find more than one End city? The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city) says that End cities are spawned **randomly** and are fairly rare. Unfortunately, I did not find the information I searched.

Does the random generation mean that there may spawn multiple End cities, or does it mean that End cities spawn at random places? Is there any way to get more rare items like Elytra?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes, more end cities are spawned.

On a server I play on with a couple other people (vanilla with spigot), we have found approximately 8 end cities so far.

It did take a while to find them all, but so far about 7 people have elytra. (a couple fell in the void)

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that multiple end cities spawn, and have in fact found three within renderable distance of each other. However, not all end cities contain end ships; I've found about a dozen cities so far, but only 6 of them had ships.

Comment: End cities are completely different than ships, they don't spawn together. They may spawn near by chance, but not automatically.

Comment: @RikerW That's actually not true. One of the possible sections of an end city is a pier, and the pier always spawns a boat casting off from it. The boats do not spawn anywhere else besides these piers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you kill the Ender Dragon, 1 portal is spawned up in the air to get to an end city. To spawn the dragon again, place a few end crystals ([crafting recipe here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZPMB.png)) on the portal to spawn another dragon. When you kill that dragon, another portal is spawned, and on and on.